# epsilon delta proof with triangle inequality

Tags: calculus, analysis, epsilon-delta

For one of the example problems from lecture, we were asked to show that for any $a \neq 1$ from the definition of a limit that the limit as $x$ approaches $a$ for $f(x)=x^2/(x-1)=a^2/(a-1)$.

after the $|f(x)-L|$ and merging the fractions together, she used the triangle inequality to obtain $((|a||x|+|a|+|x|)/(|x-1||a-1|)) |x-a|$ from $|(ax^2-x^2-a^2x+a^2)/(x-1)(a-1)|$

I am a bit confused on what was defined as $|a|$ and $|b|$ for the triangle inequality (|a+b| <= |a| + |b|). In other words, can anyone help explain how the equation was broken up? thanks

Comment: Which $b$? There is no $b$ in what you wrote.

Comment: sorry, i should have specified. I meant |b| as in the definition of the triangle inequality: |a+b| <= |a| + |b|

Comment: You should really call your $a$ and $b$ something else, because the $a$ in your problem and the $a$ in $|a+b|\leq |a|+|b|$ are not the same $a$.

Comment: sorry, I just copied what my instructor wrote and this is how she did/explained it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Factoring by parts we have

$\left|\frac{(ax^2-x^2-a^2x+a^2)}{(x-1)(a-1)}\right| = \left|\frac{(x-a)(ax-a-x)}{(x-1)(a-1)}\right| = |x-a| \frac{|ax-a-x|}{|x-1||a-1|} \le |x-a| \frac{|a||x|+|a|+|x|}{|x-1||a-1|} $.

The triangle inequality is used to obtain

$|ax-a-x| \le |a||x|+|a|+|x|$